# Empty response body with POST requests to Facebook Ads API

Tags: python, facebook, curl

I am trying to post an image to Facebook's Ads API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage, the example they have is

```
curl \
-F 'test.zip=@test.zip' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages"
```

But when I do this in requests:

```
payload = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
           image_name: post_image}

r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, stream=True)
```

I get an empty response body. How do I fix this so I can get the response body?

Comment: do you have a whitelisted app?

Comment: I do, and when I use curl, I get the response as mentioned in the documentation. Only when I use python with requests, I get empty content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently released the Facebook Python Ads API SDK (don't know if that's on your radar). But you can batch create via zip using the following code:

```
from facebookads.objects import AdImage

image = AdImage(parent_id='act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>')
image[AdImage.Field.filename] = './test.zip'
image.remote_create(batch=True)

# Output image hash.
print image[AdImage.Field.hash]
```

The GitHub README covers bootstrapping your script with your app id, access token, etc.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

Answer (score 1):

When trying with Python, you need to open image in binary mode first then give that into **files** key. Payload should be given separately having access_token only. You are getting empty response because of call being failed to upload that image.

```
file_obj = {'filename': open(local_image_path, 'rb')}
payload = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}
response = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, files=file_obj)
```

You will get a response like this :

```
{
    "id" : 123456789
}
```

Hope this helps.